# Apache ImportError: No module named _socket in wsgi deployment on Django

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, apache2.2

I am using WSGI 3.3 for Python 2.7.3 (32bit) for Apache 2.2. I downloaded the wsgi from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so and just renamed it and transferred it to the APACHE modules.

I have been trying to deploy an application but keep on receiving the `ImportError: no module named _socket`. I have included my wsgi and error logs.

I am not sure as to what I am doing wrong. I thought maybe I could include a PythonPath but am not sure. I can try to provide more information if needed. Thank you in advance.

APACHE CONFIG:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<Directory C:/Users/xxxxd/Documents/cahd>
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/xxxxd/Documents/cahd/cahd/django.wsgi
```

WSGI FIle:

```
import os, sys    
sys.path.append('C:/Users/xxxxd/Documents)
sys.path.append('C:/Users/xxxxd/Documents/cahd/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'cahd.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The error was:

```
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File "C:/Users/xxxxd/Documents/cahd/django.wsgi", line 10, in 
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File "C:\django\Django-1.4.1\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 8, in 
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] from django import http
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File "C:\django\Django-1.4.1 \django\http\_init_.py", line 11, in 
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] from urllib import urlencode, quote
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 26, in 
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] import socket
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in 
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] import _socket
[Mon Nov 19 09:44:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named _socket
```

Comment: Check out http://brettweiss.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/windows-vista-django-dll-issue-running-python-managepy-runserver/ Same issue?

Comment: Not quite, my application works thru runserver. In fact, even my helloworld.wsgi works through apache. It's just that when I modify the httpd.conf for my own application it creates an error....

Comment: Please edit your question and add what mod_wsgi configuration you added to the Apache configuration file. Also indicate where you got the mod_wsgi binary from and what the name of it was before you downloaded it and renamed it.

Comment: Try reinstalling your Python and make sure it is installed for all users. This problem used to arise with Python 2.7.0 (I think) and upgrading Python helped. Maybe if you have reinstalled at some point, but you didn't install for all users when upgrading and something has been missed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although reinstalling python might have worked. I figured out that _socket was a _socket.pyd file located in the DLLs folder, by adding that to my pythonpath in windows I was able to make my application work. Thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3):

Try to include/add  directory "C:\Python27\DLLs" to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. This solve the problem of _socket on my system. if you check the folder there are some files there including _socket.pyd

Answer (score 0):

Hi I met this issue when I am re-installing Django and Python2.7.3, which bothered my almost 2 hours. Finally I resolved it by removing Python 2.7.3, but installing Python 2.7.6. Hope it works for you too, good luck!